# How to navigate to a resource by path from the xml file in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, intellij-idea, navigation

I have an xml file (***src/main/resources/all_suites.xml***) with information about test suites for TestNG framework. It looks like this:

```
<!-- shopping, booking and retrieve-->
<suiteRef path="suite_shopping_create_order_retrieve.xml"/>

<!-- shopping, booking and fulfillment-->
<suiteRef path="suite_shopping_booking_air.xml"/>
```

All these references point **to existing files** with specific test cases. They are located in the same place (src/main/resources/)

In Eclipse I can hover each path value (*e.g. suite_shopping_booking_air.xml*), click left mouse button and the corresponding file will be opened in the editor.

https://gyazo.com/d95ef56fc2fd43c9d0cb81fcdf8094e8

How can do the same thing in Idea Community Edition?

P.S. I know about all Idea navigation opportunities (Ctrl+N, Ctrl+Shift+N and etc) but they don't satisfy me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [TestNG DTD](http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php), you will not find `suiteRef` there.

IntelliJ IDEA supports `suite-file` and `suite-files` navigation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, @CrazyCoder. But is it possible to navigate through the elements of xml file that don't have XSD or DTD ?  

I mean, I use not pure TestNG but an own framework over TestNG. So all my xml files don't comply with TestNG DTD. So it's just simple xml file that has a reference to another xml file in the same directory. Eclipce can navigate to it. Can Idea do the same thing ?

Comment: No, IntelliJ IDEA can't do it.